# SalesForce Apex SOAP Callout to External Endpoint

Tags: soap, wsdl, salesforce

Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to have SalesForce push out account information to a billing system (external) via a SOAP API. The billing system doesn't have a WSDL that I can generate an Apex Class with and I have been scouring the net for information on how to create a class without a WSDL.

Q: Is it possible to interact with an external SOAP without a WSDL? And if it is possible can someone point me to some examples?

Thanks!!
--Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices:

1. Reverse engineer a WSDL from the billing system.
2. Skip the WSDL and generate your own stub classes. See this part of the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_gen_code.htm) for an example.
3. Generate your own SOAP messages and use the [HTTP classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_restful.htm) to invoke

Comment: @ Jeremy: I was reading your answer and I was wondering, can't you use Java to make a client?Also how do you create the SOAP message yourself?Are there SOAP libraries available to use?I am asking because I am starting to look into salesforce and I am completely ignorant trying to make sense out of this.